# How does versioning work for google assistant extension store data?

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to download and upload the store data to save the versions.
Like the alexa skill store data that you can download and upload with the ask cli.

Is it possible to do the same with the google assistant extension store data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gactions CLI](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions) to export your Action from the Actions on Google Console using `gactions pull`. However, it only works with the current draft of your Action, and it doesn't support pull from a specific version.